# ADFS custom claims with SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, sharepoint-on-prem, claims-based-auth, adfs

Anyone using SPFx on SP 2016 with ADFS custom claims. We seem to have an issue with custom claims. Some claims are working others are not

E.g. the list has two roles

1: General role
2. MycustomClaim1

If user has general role it works, however if they have only MycustomClaim1 it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because those custom roles were mapped to a permission level. The permission level did not have allow Web API/SOAP assigned to it. Once Web API/SOAP was added to permission level, it fixed the issue